# allow access to users in opencart website without login or registartion

Tags: php, opencart

In our opencart website we are planning to give open access to users where people can access the webiste without login or registration , can any once tell me how to give open access

Comment: Isn't that just "guest checkout"?

Comment: what is your opencart version right now ?

Comment: opencart 2.2.0.0

Comment: it was not only guest check out , need to enable access to everything in website

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an OpenCart store - yes it is possible to make a purchase without logging into the website. There are two ways to do that.

1 - You use the Guest checkout option, which is standard in the OpenCart checkout process. You do not need to have an account in the store and you can just fill in your personal details as a guest.

2 - There is an extension for OpenCart that also lets you skip the registration and login process in the website. It’s called [SuperQuickCheckout](https://isenselabs.com/products/view/superquickcheckout-15-seconds-2-fields-checkout). The way it works is it lets you make an order by just filling out two fields with your phone number and email address. The order is submitted. From there on the store owner contacts you for your personal details and the order is processed manually.

If however you mean the official OpenCart website - there is no way to make a purchase without being logged in. Except if you are downloading a free product.

I hope that’s helpful! Good luck and have fun with OpenCart!

Thanks..